# Is is possible to use std::map in C++ with a class without any copy operator?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, stdmap

I'm using a Class (Object) that doesn't have any copy operator : it basically cannot be copied right now. I have a

`std::map<int,Object> objects`

variable that lists objects with an int identifier. How could I add an Object to this map without having to use copy operators?
I tried

`objects.insert(std::pair<0,Object()>);`

but that won't compile. I would just like to create my object initially inside the map using the default constructor, but writing

`objects[0];` fails... 
Thanks :)

Comment: `std::map` needs to store some sort of value. If not a copy of `Object`, perhaps a pointer to `Object`, assuming the `Object` isn't going to go away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++03, objects that are stored in STL containers *must* be copyable.  This is because a STL container's `std::allocator` actually uses the placement version of the `new` operator to copy construct the objects in pre-allocated memory blocks, and that requires the existence of a copy-constructor to copy the actual instance of the object you're wanting to add to the container into the memory address that had been pre-allocated by the container's allocator. So your only option would be to store pointers to your objects rather than the objects themselves.  Therefore, you could do the following:

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Object> > objects;
objects.insert(std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<Object> >(0, new Object());
```

Comment: Would give an upvote- if you were using smart pointers. Manual deletion code is badness.

Comment: Well, that's what I did. Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Not in C++03. How are you going to get the object from wherever it is now into the map without a copy constructor?

In C++0x then you could move into the map, and in theory, perfectly forward to construct one in place from other arguments.

Edit: You *could* swap it, if it's swappable, *and* you can default construct it in-place using `operator[]`.

```
std::map<int, Object> objmap;
objmap[2]; // Default-constructs an Object in-place
std::swap(objmap[2], Object()); // Swaps it into the map.
```

Comment: This would be the perfect solution, but objmap[2] just won't compile : `/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘Object::Object(const Object&)’`

Answer (score 3):

Since your object is not copy-constructible, you could create your map containing shared_ptr :

```
std::map<int,shared_ptr< Object > >
```

That takes care of destruction of objects.