# Does Visual Studio 2012 do this correctly? std::move

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, compiler-bug

A question I recently tried to answer seemed to be an error in vs2012's c++11 support.

Specifically, It failed to compile std::map with a non copy-constructible value_type, despite only std::move being used to insert into the map. Either the wrong insert overload is chosen, or the compiler doesn't consider the alternative.

Basically, I wan't to know if the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << is_constructible<pair<const int,unique_ptr<Foo> >, pair<const int,unique_ptr<Foo> >& >::value << '\n';
    cout << is_constructible<pair<const int,unique_ptr<Foo> >, pair<const int,unique_ptr<Foo> >&& >::value << '\n';
}
```

gives the output 01.

Comment: I've also had issues with Visual Studio 2013 using std::move

Comment: @Tips48 it was your question! small world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visual Studio` outputs(*[see it live](http://rextester.com/UKP5501)*):

```
1
1
```

Which is clearly wrong and both `gcc` and `clang` give the expected results. This bug and the original issue you are seeing may be related to these two accepted bug reports. The incorrect results from *is_constructible* may actually be unrelated to the [original bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056872/c-stdunique-ptr-wont-compile-in-map):

- [std::is_*constructible::value == true for abstract classes.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808132/std-is-constructible-t-value-true-for-abstract-classes)
- [VC11: map and unordered_map operater[] requires mapped_type to be CopyConstructible or MoveConstructible b](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776500)

Comment: sorry, a little clarification please: the original bug, as in the other answer?

Comment: it appears the compiler thinks it is copy constructible, and only discovers latter it was wrong, when it generates the copy constructor. i'll add a few more cases, if that's ok EDIT i see you were one step ahead, thanks. still, what do you mean by "original issue"?

Comment: @user3125280 I was referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056872/c-stdunique-ptr-wont-compile-in-map) as the original issue.

Comment: thought so - for reference, my answer to the other question does work, (i didn't know there was a vc online before) so there appears to be a relation - vc wrongly considers the impossible insert overload, because it assumes copy ctor exists. other compilers work correctly and don't consider that overload EDIT: actually, it works without my answer too.. so OP must of been doing something weird.. thanks anyway

Comment: @user3125280 it is a neat tool, I have what I think is a complete list [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652386/1708801) and I try to keep it up to date.