# Problems using a std::map containing a class without copy operator (Gdiplus::Image)

Tags: c++11, gdi+, smart-pointers, stdmap

It seems I am trying to fill a std::map with objects that are not copyable, and I have not achieved to do it yet.

**General problem**

I want to use std::map in order to store some objects of a type called Image (More precisely, it is Gdiplus::Image). I cannot write things like:

```
map<string, Gdiplus::Image> loadedImages ;
Gdiplus::Image newImage( CString("totoro.png") );
loadedImages.insert(std::pair<string, Gdiplus::Image>( "totoro", newImage ) );
```

Function "insert" seems to be the problem here. The compiler says:

```
'Gdiplus::Image::Image' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Gdiplus::Image'
```

I am not sure that it is the right explaination, but it seems that "Image" lacks of a public method used in function "insert". (Copy operator ? Copy constructor ?).

**What I have tried**

I tried to use references in the map, but it seems putting references in containers never works. I tried to use raw pointers, but I had got errors when I tried to delete all the images in the destructor. I happened across [this other (and quite similar) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231336/is-is-possible-to-use-stdmap-in-c-with-a-class-without-any-copy-operator) and I have begun to care about smart pointers. So now, I am trying, as recommended in the answer, with std::shared_ptr. However, my case is slightly different.

I want to write a function "find" that returns an image. "find" gives the image found in the map if the key (its path) exists, else it loads the image, add it to the map and returns it. So I cannot create a new image inside the parenthesis as I need the pointer.

The only version I came up with, that can compile is:

(Drawer.h)

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <Gdiplus.h>

using std::map ;
using std::shared_ptr ;

class CDrawer
{
public:
    CDrawer(void); 
    ~CDrawer(void);
    void drawImage(string p_pathToPicture)

private:
    map<string, shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Image>> m_loadedImages ; // Keep every image in memory instead of loading them each time. Each image has its path as a key.

    Gdiplus::Image* findImage(string& p_path); // get the image from the map if the image is already loaded, else load it.
};
```

(Drawer.cpp) (Constructors and destructors are empty)

```
void CDrawer::drawImage(string p_pathToImage)
{
    // get the bounding rectangle of the image
    //...

    Gdiplus::Image* l_image = findImage(p_pathToImage);

    // Draw the image.
    //...
}

Gdiplus::Image* CDrawer::findImage(string& p_pathToImage)
{
    auto iterator = m_loadedImages.find(p_pathToImage);

    if (iterator == m_loadedImages.end() ) // image not found, so we have not already loaded it
    {
        shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Image> l_newImage(   new Gdiplus::Image( CString( p_pathToImage.c_str()) )   ); // Load the image (I know I have to add error code)
        m_loadedImages.insert( std::pair<string, shared_ptr<Gdiplus::Image>>( p_pathToImage, l_newImage ) ); // Add the image to the list
        return l_newImage.get() ;

    }
    else return iterator->second.get() ;  // image found, so it is already loaded and we provide the existing one.      
}
```

But it gives the following error during run time, when the destructor of Drawer is called:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00C18CEE in MyProgramm.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02F36D78
```

Does someone knows where I am wrong, or if there is a simpler or better solution?

Comment: use `unique_ptr` for uniquely owned data.  Second, someone else is deleting your images on you.

Comment: I have just tried to replace every "shared_ptr" by "unique_ptr". Indeed, it seems better designed, as the map is the only owner of the images. Sadly, I get the following compilation error : 
`error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Comment: Move more you are trying to copy.  Or don't move take references.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your first advice ("Move more you are trying to copy")... Concerning references, how should I do it ? I can't use a map of references, and I can't use a map of plain objects (in order to make "findImage" return a reference), as a copy operator seems to be required to fill the map. Also, you have said someone is deleting my images on me. Does it mean Gdiplus could have his own system of memory management, or is it a smart pointer feature I do not use well ? (Sorry for all these questions :) )

Comment: Using private member is probably because you are copying a unique ptr.  Which is not allowed, you need to `std::move` it into the place you store it.  And when reading it, take a reference to the unique ptr, not a copy.  "Someone is deleting it" -- it cpuld be you deleting them twice, I have no idea.  Lacking a [mcve], I can guess.

Comment: Well... As a complete stack overflow newbie I was not aware of the need of a minimal, complete and verifiable example. So I have prepared one in a separate project and... guess what? It worked with a "shared_ptr" version, and also with a "unique_ptr" version, thanks to the tip concerning std::move you gave me. It means the images are indeed deleted somewhere else in the program, and now I realize my question isn't relevant. So what should I do? Delete the question? This is embarrassing. :] Anyway, thanks for everything, I'll keep this good practice in mind for my next questions. :)